# Initializing a vector of strings

Tags: c++, string, vector, initialization

I'm trying to initialize a vector of strings (from Stroustrup Programming p 375):

```cpp
vector<string> month_input_table = {"jan", "feb", "mar"};
```

(in the book he lists all 12 months).

With VS 2019 (community) I get an error:

> No instance of constructor vector<T>::vector (with T = std::string) matches the argument list

A similar previous post suggested upgrade from VS 2012, as this sort of initialization was new to C++11.  Is that my problem?  How can I tell that I'm running at least C++14?

Curiously, `vector<string> month_input_table = {"jan", "feb"};` works, but when I get over two elements, I get the constructor error.

Comment: `#if __cplusplus < 201402L` `#error Must be using C++14 or later` `#endif` near the top of your source file.

Comment: @CliffW, Would you please show us the error you see ? Is it a compile or run-time error ? (Honestly, it should not give you any error).

Comment: I tried the code using mingw compiler and it works ok. In addition I tried `vector<char*> my_vec = {"HelloWorld" , "SomeOtherStuff"}` and it also works ok (there are some warnings but overall it looks ok). Can you include your entire code along with detailed error?

Comment: Are you looking for the `/std:c++14` (or similar) option? (`/std:c++17`, `/std:c++latest`)

Comment: @ARK1375 Well, the code you posted shouldn't work since C++11. String literals are const.

Comment: [No reason why this shouldn't work](https://wandbox.org/permlink/gVsPBWILwS0GXztU)

Comment: Thanks to everyone.  The actual line, copied from my file is: vector <string> print_month_table = { "jan", "feb", "mar" };  As soon as I type the quote before "mar" the red squggle appears under the leading curly brace.  I tried the #if __cplusplus preprocesseor directive and it loout.  If anyone has direction for me, it would be appreciated.  oks like I did get the error, so I suspect my setup of VS2019 is running something pre C++14.  I'll poke around and see if I can figure it

Comment: 1201ProgramAlarm: suspect I am looking for something like that - where to I look/implement?

Comment: Sorry for all this rookie angst.  I went to the project/properties/c-c++/language options and found the language standard to be "Default ISO C++14"  I had the options of "c++ 17" and "latest C++ working draft" but they actually made things a bit worse - the editor flagged an error as soon as I typed the first open quote, rather than waiting till the third.  The work-around isn't hard, but I'd sure like to know what I'm doing wrong here.